# My Scss styles aren't showing on my components

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I don't get any errors, but I can't get the styles to change when they should be changing. I'm brand new to Ruby on Rails so I'm trying to learn on the fly here. Here's what I have.

```js
mediumr_controller.rb:

class MediumrController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end
end

application.html.rb :

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Mediumrails</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  </head>

  <body>
    <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>
```

```css
application.scss:

@import "bootstrap";

mediumr.scss:

testHeading {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
views/layouts/application.html.erb :

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Mediumrails</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  </head>

  <body>
    <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>

views/layouts/mediumr/index.html.erb

<%= react_component 'Main' %>
```

the component main.jsx shows up when I run the ruby server and it shows the text I'm trying to display (and has the className = "testHeading"), but the color of the text doesn't change. Does anyone have any idea what could be the issue?

I'm using rails version 5.1.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside of your `mediumr.scss` make sure that your `.testHeading` selector has a `.` before `testHeading`.

---

Right now you have:

```
testHeading {
  color: red;
}
```

Change this to:

```
.testHeading {
  color: red;
}
```

Also, inside of `application.scss` make sure to import your `mediumr.scss` stylesheet like so:

```
// application.scss

@import "mediumr";
```

Comment: wow what a rookie mistake, good catch! I noticed though that I had to move that code to application.scss for it work. I'd like for it to remain in mediumr.scss . Do i have to import mediumr into application.scss? I thought the pipeline would do that automatically.

Comment: No problem :) Yes you do have to import `mediumr.scss` inside of `application.scss` in order to use that stylesheet. I'll update my answer with that syntax in case you need it.

Comment: I got it by doing @import "mediumr". Thanks though! I'll accept your answer in 5 minutes when it lets me.

Comment: That's it - I didn't need to update my answer I guess :)